# My "Vigenere CS 50" project doesn't work well

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

I'm currently working on Vigenere CS 50 Problem. The code seems working pretty well, but sometimes the output is being confused by further symbols just being added at the end of the output string. For instance when I'm encrypting "a" with a key of "a" the output will be sometimes just ok as "a" and sometimes can look like "a<" or "aR" or "a{7"...

At the same time, the code works ok with much longer keys and more complex plain text, so I'm really confused now and do not really know what to start with.

Could you please have a look of the code?

Thanks in advance,
Vladimir

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
    printf("Usage: ./vigenere k\n");
    return 1;
    } 

    string k = (argv[1]);

    int key[strlen(k)];

    int n = strlen(k);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(k[i]))
        {
            if (isupper(k[i]))
            {
                key[i] = (int)k[i] - 65;
            }
            else
            {
                key[i] = (int)k[i] - 97;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Key must be alphabetical\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    string p;

    do 
    {
        printf("plaintext: ");
        p = get_string();
    } while (p == NULL); 

    char c[strlen(p)];

    int cn = 0;

    for (int j = 0, m = strlen(p); j < m; j++)
    {
        if (isalpha(p[j]))
        {
            if (isupper(p[j])) 
            {
                c[j] = (((int)p[j] + key[cn] - 65) % 26 + 65);
            }
            else
            {
                c[j] = (((int)p[j] + key[cn] - 97) % 26 + 97);
            }

            cn++;
            cn = cn % n;
        }
        else 
        {
            c[j] = p[j];
        }
    }

    printf("ciphertext: %s", c);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why the `C#` and `C++` tags?

Comment: Clearer using `key[i] = (int)k[i] - 'A';` and `key[i] = (int)k[i] - 'a';`

Comment: BTW your problem is that you are not null-terminating your string

Comment: @LPs no room in the string to null-terminate it either

Comment: For future reference, please try to make the titles of your questions descriptive of your problem. Something like "output string has random characters at the end" would have been better. The fact that this is a Vigenere cipher program is irrelevant and we already know it doesn't work well because otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: this line: `char c[strlen(p)];` declares a char array that is 1 short.  Need room for the NUL termination byte: Suggest: `char c[ strlen(p) +1];` followed by: `memset( c, '\0', strlen(p)+1 );` so the resulting string will be NUL terminated.  Note: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` so the variables be assigned to should also be `size_t`

Comment: the header file/library `cs50` is not portable, strongly suggest using the functions found in the standard C library(s)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  For the 'wrong parameter count' error, suggest using: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s  key\n", argv[0] );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good old fashioned "not null terminated" string. C style strings (which is what you've created with `char c[strlen(p)];`) have no length associated with them. To calculate their length, the standard library assumes they'll be terminated with `\0` (a null byte). You're not doing this, so when you `printf`, it carries on printing until it finds one.

You need to:

1. Allocate enough space for the null byte: `char c[strlen(p) + 1];`
2. Put it on the end: `c[strlen(p)] = 0;`